# setDefaults is deprecated in Notification.Builder

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

`setDefaults` in Notification.Builder is deprecated in android O and above (SDK >= 26)

Also `setSound`

This is my code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        b.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_luncher_new)
                .setContentTitle(Title)
                .setTicker(Title)
                .setContentText(Msg)
                .setChannelId("cid")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(Msg))
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    }
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(id, b.build());`
```

What should I replace? i don't find any useful example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setDefaults` should be replaced with use of the following

- NotificationChannel.enableVibration(boolean)
- NotificationChannel.enableLights(boolean)
- NotificationChannel.setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)

[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int))

`setSound` should be replaced with use of

- NotificationChannel.setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)

[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setSound(android.net.Uri))

Answer (score 2):

I use this function now and work's perfectly

```
private void CreateNotificationMessage(Context ctx,String Title,String Msg){
    int id=15;
    Intent intent= new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);
    Notification.Builder b = new Notification.Builder(ctx);

    NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_luncher)
            .setContentTitle(Title)
            .setTicker(Title)
            .setContentText(Msg)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel("cid", "name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        b.setChannelId("cid");
        mChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .build());
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(id, b.build());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setDefaults(int)):

> public Notification.Builder setDefaults (int defaults)
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 26. use
> NotificationChannel.enableVibration(boolean) and
> NotificationChannel.enableLights(boolean) and
> NotificationChannel.setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes) instead.
>
> public Notification.Builder setSound (Uri sound, AudioAttributes audioAttributes)
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 26. use
> NotificationChannel.setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes) instead.

You need to change your method's signature.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning from Android O (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. 
These configurations can be set on notification channel using following dedicated methods:

1. [NotificationChannel.enableVibration(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#enableVibration(boolean))
2. [NotificationChannel.enableLights(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#enableLights(boolean))
3. [NotificationChannel.setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes))